# tail -f OR less +F how to highlight new lines

Tags: linux, bash, console

Is there any way to highlight, i.e. bold, or colorize new added lines since last change?

For example, I am watching a log file with multiple similar errors in PHP error_log (different line or function name, etc)... And I have to look at timestamps where one set of errors ends and another begins (page refresh)

It would be very helpful if there is a way to highlight, but only last added lines.

I am looking for solution to run on macOS and Linux in console.

Comment: This does not highlight, but what I use to do in order to know new lines in a log file is executing `tail -f` and then give manually several carriage returns, so that new lines will be easily identified after those carriage returns.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `watch` command, if your system has it.  The command:

```
watch -d tail /your/file/here
```

will display the file and highlight the differences character by character. Note that you do not want to use the `-f` option in this case.

Ubuntu has it.  For OSX, you can can use `brew install watch` if you have [`homebrew`](https://brew.sh/) installed or `sudo ports install watch` if you use [`ports`](https://www.macports.org/install.php).

Another bonus is that it works for any command that has output that changes over time.  We have even used it with `ls -l` to watch the progress of backups and file compressions.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on `grep`'s line buffering mode.

1. Using tail

   ```
   tail -f fileName | grep --line-buffered my_pattern
   ```
2. Using less

   ```
   less +F fileName | grep --line-buffered my_pattern
   ```
3. Using watch & tail to highlight new lines

   ```
   watch -d tail fileName
   ```

> Note:  For linux based systems.

Answer (score 0):

"tail" itself does not offer a serious way to do this. But give "multitail" a closer look:

https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/

And for Mac OSX:

http://macappstore.org/multitail/

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried multitail but it does not offer this funcionallity by default. So far I found some workaround. Enter throws separator with time in multitail, but that is manual action, I am looking for something more automated.